# Cycle detection in a Multigraph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I would like to list all the cycles in an undirected multigraph.

[Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) was written for a directed graph.  Will it work for multigraphs? If not, is there an cycle listing algorithm for undirected multigraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to reduce your problem to Tarjan, depending on how you want to count cycles.

First, apply two transformations to your graph:

1. Convert to a directed graph by replacing each undirected edge with a pair of opposing directed edges.
2. For each pair of nodes, collapse edges pointing the same direction into a single edge.

You'll be left with a directed graph.  Apply Tarjan's algorithm.

Now, depending on what you consider a cycle, you may or may not be done.  If a cycle is set of nodes (that happen to posses the required edges), then you can read the cycles directly off the transformed graph.

If a cycle is a set of edges (sharing the required nodes), then you need to "uncollapse" the edges introduced in step 2 above.  For each collapsed edge, enumerate along the set of real edges it replaced.  Doing so for each edge in each collapsed cycle will yield all actual cycles in a combinatorial explosion.  Note that this will generate spurious two-cycles which you'll need to prune.

To illustrate, suppose the original graph has three nodes `A`, `B` and `C`, with two edges between `A` and `B`, one between `B` and `C` and one between `A` and `C`.  The collapsed graph will be a triangle, with one cycle.

Having found a cycle between the three nodes, walk each combination of edges to recover the full set of cycles.  Here, there are two cycles: both include the `A` to `C` and `B` to `C` edges.  They differ in which `A` to `B` edge they choose.

If the original graph also had two edges between `B` and `C`, then there would be four expanded graphs.  The total number of expanded cycles is the product of the edge counts: `4 == 2 * 2 * 1`.

Comment: could you draw a picture of the collapsing and uncollapsing i'm not sure what you mean?